# set filename tab-completion in dash case insensitive

Tags: shell, case-insensitive, dash-shell

I’m using dash shell filename tab-completion feature to complete file names.However default tab-completion in dash case-sensitive.How can I force filename tab-completion in dash case insensitive?

In bash, I can add "set completion-ignore-case on" to /etc/inputrc, however it makes no effects in dash. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of dash and what OS? Mine doesn't have completion. Are you using `rlwrap` by any chance?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I haven't been able to find any reference to filename completion in dash in the documentation or the source except as a reference to "future plans". Google searches turn up things saying specifically that it doesn't have it. How are you able to get it to do it at all? The only way I can think of is with `rlwrap`. If you do `ps w` is `rlwrap` running?